# htaccess redirect parameter into directory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I setup a slightly weird hierarchy where index reads the URI to decide the action instead of using actual subdirectories, example: site.com/base/action/

Im moving over from the old system to this new one, but I cant get the redirects to work. What I need is: /base/?param[]=value to do an external redirect to /base/param/value/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?)(\[\])?=([^&]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?base/?$ /base/%1/%3/?%4 [L,R=301]
```

This will also preserve any query string that may be after `param[]=value`. You can alternatively just clobber the entire query string altogether by removing the `%4` at the end of the rule's target.